# Flexible heater

Tags: resistance, camera, flexible, heater, thermal-camera

Im design flexible heater for camera lens holder with thick trace (5 mil), 
According bto Ohm law, the trace resistance is 7 ohm, with 2.5V the total power is 1W.
Do you think is good heater design?
Maybe I need to use a different material than standard copper?

Thanks.

Comment: I would not call "5mil" a "thick trace". Do you mean 5mm? 5mil is about the width of a human hair.

Comment: My aeroplane has a wingspan of 30 feet - is it a good aeroplane design?

Comment: Are you trying to use thin traces with high resistance to generate a heat source and use the board+traces as a heater? There are better ways to accomplish this, please don't do it the way you described.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, I try to use wire (trace) to heat the camera lens, as you have in your rear car. You can find those products off the shelf. Just google "flexible heater"

Comment: Hi Ron, you right, I mean 5 mil trace width. 0.5 oz thickness

Comment: @NCalif resistance is based on cross-sectional area, not simply trace width. How thick is the copper trace? Also, you are wanting to have heat conduct from the trace to something else. How do you plan to thermally connect them? This is probably much more important than your heater element design.

Comment: @Aaron by 3M adhesive material, this material have ability to forward heat.

Comment: @Andyaka no offense andy, but maybe you should tone down those comments a bit, people are more willing to learn from less aggressive answers

Comment: @diegogmx you are of course entitled to your wrong opinion.

Comment: what will 5mil trace be formed on? will the copper be protected? Is this a flex circuit? So many details left out of the OP.

Comment: @Aaron 5mil trace act like 8 ohm resistor (long 5mil trace). This is flex PCB.